Masking the column values
I have a column (varchar2) in one of the tables in Oracle12c, which I need to mask with an update statement. The table has around 1 million records all of which needs to be updated, so I think a direct SQL update would be much better here rather than PL/SQL block.
Masking Conditions:

Each word in the value should retain its 1st and last characters
Remaining each character in the word should be replaced by "x"
Overall length of the value should remain same as original value

Tried with regex_replace but unable to sort out the exact regex which I can use to achieve above.
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(column1, '(\w)(\w+)(\w)', '\1' || RPAD('x', LENGTH('\2'), 'x') || '\3') AS transformed_col1
FROM table1;

Tried to get the length of 2nd part, but LENGTH('\2') is always treated as literal values and always results in 2, thus replacing the middle values by 2 x's.
Sample Values:

This is a sample value

Another example of string


Expected Output:

Txxs is a sxxxxe vxxxe

Axxxxxr exxxxxe of sxxxxg



This question has a solution while the referenced other questions don't propose any real one.
